# org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException - method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj

I had same problem as [vanhre asked in Spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?74717-AspectJ-AJDT-and-Spring-AOP-exception-initializing), but in my case I couldn't change the constructor.

I'm using Spring java configuration, so it was initializing ok during jetty start, but in runtime, when I executed the functionality with my aspect it failed with exactly the same exception from the forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found later, that I need `aspectjrt` dependency in my pom.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

**edit:** Missing dependency was an error, but real problem is Eclipse + aspects combination. When I used Eclipse to build my aspect class this error occurred. Additionally when I compiled class the aspect advice was for, aspect was not called.

**solution:** you have to use maven to build your application (I'd be glad if someone find solution for Eclipse, because I'm sure I'll forget this)

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to say... I followed this link - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Betlista.. Oh. I thought you wanted to edit your post. Its ok to answer your own question of course.

Answer (score 1):

download
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.9/aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar
and add to your project

Comment: That library is many years old. The current version supporting Java 7 and 8 is 1.8.5. P.S.: And why are you answering an old question from 2012 with an already accepted answer anyway?

Comment: I have same problem and found the solution but not maven way.

Comment: I download aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar file directly and add it to my libraries, then problem solved.