# Aspects not found at runtime

Tags: java, command-line, aspectj

My project is working fine on eclipse and now I am trying to get it to work through the command prompt.

I am facing errors though after running it whenever execution goes to the pointcut. In this case, as soon as I create a customer object.

The ajc files are in the same package with the other java files, so no import statements are used.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/NoAspectBoundException
at bankwithlogging.Customer.<init>(Customer.java:16)
at bankwithlogging.CustomerListener.actionPerformed(CustomerListener.java:55)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 38 more
```

Compilation command:

```
ajc -classpath="C:\aspectj1.9\lib\aspectjrt.jar" -source 1.8 -target 1.8 bankwithlogging/*.java bankwithlogging/*.aj
```

Run command:

```
java bankwithlogging.BankWithLogging
```

Please let me know if you know where I went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289067/8721358

Comment: @KevinNiland I have provided the path to aspectjrt.jar in my ajc command. I don't think I am using spring though nor maven so I don't know what is pom...
It seems also his issue arises when using eclipse which is the opposite to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jar file and the folder that contains the generated .class files in the classpath of run command

```
java -cp C:\aspectj1.9\lib\aspectjrt.jar;C:\Users\pc\source\repos\AspectJ\BankWithLogging\BankWithLoggingAspects\src bankwithlogging.BankWithLogging
```

Comment: Yes, that is why it is called the AspectJ **runtime** library (or "rt" for short in `aspectjrt`). you need it on the runtime classpath, of course.

Comment: Wow that's a good way to look at it now that you mention it